# RN- IOS directory not found for option AppAuth

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm running "React-native run-ios" or running via xCode and getting this error, what's the problem? Thank you.

Note: I am using project.xcworkspace.

XCode error output;

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L-L/Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXX-xxxxxxxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppAuth'
 ld: library not found for -lAppAuth
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

package.json

```
> "dependencies": {
>     "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
>     "@react-native-community/google-signin": "^4.0.3",
>     "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
>     "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.5",
>     "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "0.1.0-rc.2",
>     "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",
>     "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.5.1",
>     "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^4.3.3",
>     "aws-amplify": "^3.0.22",
>     "aws-amplify-react-native": "^4.2.3",
>     "axios": "^0.19.2",
>     "lodash": "^4.17.15",
>     "lottie-react-native": "^3.5.0",
>     "moment": "^2.27.0",
>     "react": "16.13.1",
>     "react-native": "0.63.1",
>     "react-native-aws-signature": "0.0.9",
>     "react-native-camera": "git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.git",
>     "react-native-easy-toast": "^1.2.0",
>     "react-native-fbsdk": "^2.0.0",
>     "react-native-flags": "^1.0.0",
>     "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
>     "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
>     "react-native-permissions": "^2.1.5",
>     "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.4.1",
>     "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
>     "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.3",
>     "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
>     "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.7.0",
>     "react-native-vega-scroll-list": "^1.0.0",
>     "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
>     "redux": "^4.0.5",
>     "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
>     "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
>     "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
>     "redux-promise-middleware": "^6.1.2",
>     "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
>     "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.16"  
> },
```